# fix a transparent background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a question mark sign that on hover displays some tips about the feature.

```
/*-------------------------
    Inline help tip
--------------------------*/
.help-tip-wrapper{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.help-tip{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{
    display: none;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before{
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}
```

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-inline">
                <p class="pt-3 pl-3">Categories</p>
                <div class="help-tip-wrapper">
                    <div class="help-tip">
                        <p>Please select a category before registering a terminal. You can create nested categories.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that on hover, the text is displayed on a transparent background. Which makes everything visible from behind and also makes the information less readable.

How can I make the background non transparent?

Comment: what do you mean by transparent background? The text on hover shows a black background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `position: relative;` on `p` tag:

```css
/*-------------------------
    Inline help tip
--------------------------*/
.help-tip-wrapper{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.help-tip{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{
    display: none;
    background-color: purple;;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
}

.help-tip p:before{
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-inline">
                <p class="pt-3 pl-3">Categories</p>
                <div class="help-tip-wrapper">
                    <div class="help-tip">
                        <p>Please select a category before registering a terminal. You can create nested categories.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>asfasddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: do you know how to remove the bookmark sign?

Comment: Sure mate :) try toremove `content: ''` from `.help-tip p:before`